# Cells appear the same but don't match in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm using sum to give me the percentages of each category I have in a column called Time Weekdays. I know that's bad spelling protocol but I didn't create that. This is what I'm using for each query:

`Sum(IIf([Time Weekdays]=("4-5 h/day"),1,0))/Count(*) AS [% 4-5h/day]`

The problem is I found that my percentages across all the categories were not adding up to 100. I realised when looking at the filters on my table that certain cells are coming up as two different categories even though they appear to be the exact same.

[image]

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Bizarre. Build a query that calcs the length of the [Time Weekdays] data. Maybe there are extra non-printing characters. Are the [Time Weekdays] entries input by a combobox with RowSource using a lookup table?

Comment: Perhaps `UPDATE tablename SET [Time Weekdays] = "4-5 h/day" WHERE [Time Weekdays] LIKE "*4-5 h/day*"` might help?